# SwiftUI: App crashes when resizing ScrollView with 3 TextField inside HStack on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

Here is the full example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            HStack {
                ForEach(1...3, id: \.self) { idx in
                    TextField("", text: .constant("text \(idx)"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Xcode version: 11.5

When I am resizing window app crashes with the following exception:

```
Assertion failure in -[_TtC7SwiftUIP33_A874FC5B9DB530D4375C25AE2AA39DF215HostingClipView setBoundsOrigin:], /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1894.40.150/AppKit.subproj/NSView.m:5646
```

Am I doing something wrong?

**Update**:

When I change number of TextFields to 4 resizing works fine.

Comment: SwiftUI bug, submit feedback to Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is workaround. Fixed variant tested with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.4

```
struct CrashedContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gp in
            ScrollView {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(1...3, id: \.self) { idx in
                        TextField("", text: .constant("text \(idx)"))
                    }
                }.frame(width: gp.size.width)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've also submitted feedback to Apple as you suggested